# Rendering of offline page not working on live server

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I tried rendering an offline page on my service worker, It works well on  my localhost but apparently it does not work on my live server and I don't get any errors

```
event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request));

  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function(error) {
      //console.log( ' Network request Failed. Serving content from cache: ' + error );

      //Check to see if you have it in the cache
      //Return error page if file is document file else return failed

      function fe(filename) {
         return filename.slice((filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
      }

      // Fetch the request extention 
      let extention = fe(event.request.url)

      if(extention === 'php' || extention === ''){
        console.log('rendering Offline')
        // match offline only if request is for a page not an asset
        return caches.match(offlineUrl);
      }else{
        console.log('Still searching: ' + extention)
        return caches.open('saving-nest').then(function (cache) {
          return cache.match(event.request).then(function (matching) {
            var report =  !matching || matching.status == 404?Promise.reject('no-match'): matching;
            return report
          });
        });  
      }      
    })
  );
```

On a live server the offline page is not rendered instead the present request remains rendered

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the last '.' is actually '.php' it may be site.com/site and com/site is not a matched on

```
if(extention === 'php' || extention === '')
```

so use this instead, works for me

```
if(extention === /php/.test(extention) || extention == 'htaccess' || extention === '' || /com/.test(extention))
```